# How to reliably disable the ZZ map in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to disable the `ZZ` mapping in vim, as I found myself accidentally exiting from vim too much by it when trying to use `>>` (I use a spanish keyboard).

My attempt is quite obvious:

```
nnoremap ZZ <Nop>
```

While it works for my use case, I found that doing `Z<wait 1 second>Z` still triggers the "save and quit" behavior.

As I understand Vim waits `timeoutlen` milliseconds and, if that time passes, the map doesn't fire and Vim uses the default `ZZ` behavior.

My question is, how can I reliably disable `ZZ` even when `timeoutlen` passes without changing the timeout config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While writing the question I began tinkering with an idea, and finally come to this:

```
nnoremap Z <Nop>
nnoremap ZZ <Nop>
```

This works always, no matter how you press `ZZ`; if you press it and waits, the first map fires and clears the `Z`, if you don't wait the second fires.

I hope this is useful to someone else.

Comment: I suggest doing the same to ZQ just to be sure, since it's even more dangerous (quit without saving).